# How to use HeadContent to replace meta tags in Blazor Wasm not-hosted

Tags: seo, meta-tags, blazor-webassembly

I'm on .NET6 and I have a Blazor Wasm application that is hosted as an Azure Static Website.
I understand how to add meta tags like `description` and `keywords` using

```
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<HeadContent>
    <meta name="description" content="Blazor WASM index page.">
</HeadContent>
```

But I want to add the needed meta tags to index.html and let the component **overwrite** them.
Now the component is adding them. Resulting in duplicate meta tags.

This line in my `Program.cs` is responsible for that:

```cs
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```

The documentation says it will add the meta tags at the end, which it does. How to make it replace any existing meta tags?

The reason I want this is so every page will at least have a full set of meta tags and I assume it is also better for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `<HeadContent>` will only overwrite tags in other `<HeadContent>` components, it will not overwrite tags in the index.html `<head>`